Meaning of lyrics in RADWIMPS - Suzume ft. Toaka
can you please help me with the difficult task to understand some lyrics in the song Suzume?
時はまくらぎ
風はにきはだ
星はうぶすな
人はかげろう

I found an answer on HiNative where someone turned the hiragana into Kanji
時は枕木 
風は和肌 
星は産土 
人は蜻蛉

About every line I would like to know the translation and a possible interpretation.
Since it is a piece of art there are no definitives.
For example:
According to Jisho the word 枕木 is a railway sleeper. The pieces of wood below train tracks that fix the tracks in place.
This can be interpreted as time holding you on a straigh line. Like the railway sleeper is fixing the track in place.
The example does not aim to be correct but it aims to convey the format I would appreciate in an answer.

These lines seem very abstract. This may be a kind of question where just getting close to a plausible interpretation would require utilizing all available knowledge about the lyricist and the film. Nevertheless, I can explain how these words are generally understood:

かげろう is a widely recognized metaphor for something ephemeral and difficult to perceive. This metaphorical meaning is better known than its original meaning ("mayfly").
まくらぎ is a word known to the general public, but it doesn't have any well-known metaphorical meanings. Since it describes time, it could be a metaphor for something that serves as an unchangeable foundation.
にきはだ and うぶすな are archaic words that the general public simply does not know. According to the dictionary, にきはだ means "soft skin", and うぶすな means "birthplace". Although the words themselves are difficult, their implied metaphors may be straightforward here.

